# jquery show/hide prevents site from opening in safari

Tags: jquery, safari, show-hide

Not very experienced here. but need to complete my website.
My issue is that jquery seems to be preventing my site from opening first time in safari.
the show and hide div function seems to be the problem
any help would be much appreciated. 
http://www.designactivists.com/sem_4_2011/barebones/ is the link.
the code looks like this. when is removed site opens perfectly.

```
<script language="javascript" src="jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#toggleButton').click(function() {
           if ($('#navbar').is(":hidden"))
           {
                $('#navbar').slideDown("slow");
           } else {
                $('#navbar').slideUp("slow");
           }
           return false;
      });
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: Safari.... hmm smells like a known problem. Try to use $(window).load(function() ...

Comment: Or perhaps try also $('#toggleButton').live('click', function(){ ...

Comment: Thanks roXon for a quick response. unfortunately it didnt work. could you suggest any alternatives. ive spent weeks trying to find a solution.

Comment: Strange, i had the same issue with Safari and window load resolved my problem. I'm mobile now. When I came home i'll give it a look.

Comment: FYI i'm using mobile safari  533.1 and from here the page won't open neither after more refreshes

Comment: i have been having a serious fiddle around and it seems the problem might just be with loading jquery.

Answer (score 1):

If IS keyword is the problem that you could achieve the same with following code:

```
$('#toggleButton').click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   $('#navbar').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

FYI: Also remove the href="#" from the toggleButton. Instead use href="javascript:void(0);". This shall not take the user to top upon clicking the link.